# Moving code just before end of body tag, but for specific page/template

Tags: magento-1.7, template, phtml

I need to put my html/js code just before end of body tag (`</body>`) on last checkout page (`\template\checkout\success.phtml`)

But after `success.phtml` I still have footer and wraper code. How to move my code from end of template `success.phtml` to end of whole page.

This needs to be only for that page, not for whole website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to ...

> app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="your/blocktype" name="your_block_name" template="path/to/file.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

Just have to add your script-(links) to `file.phtml` and maybe adjust block type.

**Edit**:

If no custom methods are required use `block type="core/template"`.

Comment: There is bunch of xml files in that folder, but there is no `local.xml` in both my and base theme.

Comment: If there is no local.xml, just create one in your theme  :)

Comment: Just i case you are the one who has upvoted and it fits for your needs, please also accept the answer. ;)

Comment: What "blocktype" should be ? When I set "checkout/onepage_success" it's at the end of template, not whole page, and if I put on "page/html_footer", it mess my footer completly, i lose some elements.

Comment: Updated my answer.